# MySQL schema name with dash causes errors for Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I'm working with `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update` in development environments and recently I've upgraded hibernate version from 5.1.0.Final to 5.2.X.Final and I've started to experience errors in hibernate's auto generated commands for my schema called `portal-appname`.

In hibernate 5.1.0 when I add a new column for a given table the following command its executed:

```
Hibernate: alter table answer add column fake integer not null
```

But in Hibernate 5.2.X, the schema is added as a prefix to the given tablename:

```
Hibernate: alter table portal-appname.answer add column fake integer not null
```

This is not a valid sql command, obviously:

```
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-appname.answer add column fake integer not null' at line 1
```

Hibernate should enclose portal-appname.table with backtips automatically as:

```
Hibernate: alter table `portal-appname`.`answer` add column fake integer not null
```

I've tried with `hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers` but it only quotes column names but not the portal-appname.table pair.

Funny thing is that hibernate 5.2.X is only using that syntax with column names, but it's not prefixing the schema in other kind of alters such as:

```
Hibernate: alter table tablename add constraint FKftsiakun1f5qp01aabdw887kp foreign key (logo) references tablename2 (id)
```

Last but not least, I'm in moment where I'm able to rename my schema to other thing. Also, I can downgrade to hibernate 5.1.0 but I want to know why hibernate has introduced this behaviour and if there's something to avoid it.

Any help is much welcome.

Comment: will it work if you put them in back-tick [ ` ] ?

Comment: I'm aware of the backtick: that's precisely what I'm expecting hibernate to do automatically. The problem is that hibernate is not enclosing portal-appname with backtips as `\`portal-appname\``

Comment: without reading your question in detail, how about you just rename the database and never ever use special characters in names again?

Comment: @fancyPants If you read my last paragraph:
_I'm in moment where I'm able to rename my schema to other thing. Also, I can downgrade to hibernate 5.1.0 but I want to know why hibernate has introduced this behaviour and if there's something to avoid it._

Answer (score 0):

To keep Hibernate 5.2+, you have to disable the shema qualifier in the dialect :

```
@Override
public NameQualifierSupport getNameQualifierSupport() {
    return NameQualifierSupport.NONE;
}
```

Sample dialect [there](https://github.com/ligoj/bootstrap/blob/master/bootstrap-business/src/main/java/org/ligoj/bootstrap/core/dao/MySQL5InnoDBUtf8Dialect.java).
Also be sure to use a specific user able to see only the target database: do not use "root". Hibernate fetches all visible tables from all databases even if different from the one you specified.